# MVC RequireHttps and redirect if not https

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, ssl, requirehttps

I've read thru many of the questions on ASP.NET MVC `[RequireHttps]` - but can't find the answer to this question:

How do you make the `[RequireHttps]` attribute switch the url to https if it was not https to start with?

I have this code:

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    return View("AnotherAction");
}

[RequireHttps]
public ActionResult AnotherAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

But I get an error saying: "The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL."

The MVC futures project has a similar attribute `[RequireSsl(Redirect = true)]`.  But that is outdated now ... What is the equivalent in MVC 2?

When someone types in the URL http://example.com/home/dosomething OR the url http://example.com/home/anotheraction, I need them to be automatically redirected to the url http**s**://example.com/home/anotheraction

EDIT this is the sequence of events:

The URL http://example.com/home/dosomething is called from another website. They redirect their users to this url (with a response.redirect or similar).

`DoSomething()` then tries to return `AnotherAction()`, but fails with the error message "The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL."

Comment: You could write a custom attribute to do that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `RequiresHttps` attribute does automatically attempt to redirect to `https://your-url`.  I verified this behavior on a site I have that uses that attribute, and also looking at the code in Reflector:

```
protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    if (!string.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.RequireHttpsAttribute_MustUseSsl);
    }
    string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
}
```

Are you sure you have your site set up to accept secure connections?  What happens if you try to browse to `https://your-url` directly?

Comment: actually as your code above shows, it only redirects for GET requests. If a POST (or HEAD, etc) request comes in, it will simply throw the Exception. An important distinction

Comment: Another consequence is that any controller action that is having [RequireHttps] and accessed via GET should also have [HttpGet] attribute to prevent the exception upon a HEAD request that is sent sometimes before/instead of its GET counterpart.

Answer (score 15):

[mvc 4] short answer:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)
  {
      Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
  }
}
```

longer answer:
to move from http to https you cant send a redirect to https after the first packet,
therefor you need to catch the packet using Application_BeginRequest,
from the Global.asax add the function and it will override the default,
the code should be something like so (Global.asax on the class level):

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection && 
      !Request.Url.Host.Contains("localhost") && 
      Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("SGAccount/Login"))
  {
      Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("http://", "https://"));
  }
}
```

i strongly suggest putting a breakpoints and inspecting the Request.Url object for any url related need.
or visit the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri_properties.aspx) confused about request.url absoluteuri vs originalstring?
so am i you can go to [dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/uri)  for examples.
this function enables you to develop on localhost and deploying your code as is.
now for every page you want to make a https redirect you need to specify it in the if condition.
to move from https to http you can use regular Response.Redirect like so:

```
if (Request.Url.Scheme.Contains("https"))
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}", Request.Url.Authority), true);
}
```

notice this also support working on the same code when developing on local host by not interrupting the original course of things pre the https addition.

also i recommend thinking about implementing some return url convention (if not already implemented) in that case you should go something like so:

```
if (Request.Url.Scheme.Contains("https"))
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}{1}", Request.Url.Authority, returnUrl), true);
}
```

this will redirect to the requested page post login.

naturally you should protect every page that shows user data, register, login and more.

Comment: Looking for string "localhost" might not always work - it could be renamed. See this similar topic with my answer explaining [how to handle HTTPS for production only](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38244992/1095493) with use of buil-in RequireHttpsAttribute inside Startup.cs (MVC 6).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that code should be placed in "global.asax."

Answer (score 3):

Http **HEAD** requests do not appear to be redirected.  When reviewing our error logs we see lots of this message, googling lands here, but after looking more at the details they have a few interesting "features"

- Request_method: **HEAD**
- User Agent: curl/7.35.0

In other words all of the failed attempts were not customer facing...

(100% credit to comment from @arserbin3 for making me realize they were all **HEAD** requests)

Answer (score 2):

**MVC4 does now redirect**

but not how you would expect.

http://www.example.com:8080/alpha/bravo/charlie?q=quux
will be redirect the client's browser to 
https://www.example.com/alpha/bravo/charlie?q=quux

**Notice the lack of a port number.**

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#test/System.Web.Mvc.Test/Test/RequireHttpsAttributeTest.cs
code test
        [Fact]
        public void OnAuthorizationRedirectsIfRequestIsNotSecureAndMethodIsGet()

confirms this is the desired behaviour.

If you would like to write a custom attribute that does include the PORT ... you can base your code on:

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/RequireHttpsAttribute.cs

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public RequireHttpsAttribute()
        : this(permanent: false)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="RequireHttpsAttribute"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permanent">Whether the redirect to HTTPS should be a permanent redirect.</param>
    public RequireHttpsAttribute(bool permanent)
    {
        this.Permanent = permanent;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the redirect to HTTPS should be a permanent redirect.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Permanent { get; private set; }

    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // only redirect for GET requests, otherwise the browser might not propagate the verb and request
        // body correctly.

        if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(MvcResources.RequireHttpsAttribute_MustUseSsl);
        }

        // redirect to HTTPS version of page
        string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url, this.Permanent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To supplement the answer already given, this is the code from the MVC 5 implementation of HandleNonHttpsRequest

```
protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    // only redirect for GET requests, otherwise the browser might not propagate the verb and request
    // body correctly.
    ...
}
```