# How to implement SSL in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssl

I am currently working on an asp.net mvc app. I am currently working on a log in feature, my aim is to somehow implement SSL so that I can send the password in plain text to the sever to be hashed there. 
In my controller Ive added the requireshttps attribute to the login action result:

```
[RequireHttps]//Enforcing SSL in a Web API Controller
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Currently it does nothing and the page should just displays a form, but I will later add the functionality to get the data from the form to the controller (most likely via an ajax call).

However now I've added this attribute i cannot load the login webpage. 
I then found this tutorial and followed the instructions with IIS manager: http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Now I get this screen when I try to access the page:

[image]

I know that I am most likely making an obvious mistake as this is my first encounter with SSL and IIS, Any ideas?

Heres a screenshot of my IIS manager:
[image]

Comment: Check your IIS site binding and make sure it has a port 443 (https) binding.

Comment: @WeTTTT added a screenshot of my IIS management I assume that is correct?

Comment: You've added an SSL Cert to your IIS server and Visual Studio is deploying content there or are you running it in Visual Studio?

Comment: IIS doesn't route this request to web api. Rather, it thinks it is a static file (see the message on the image). Make sure web config contains mvc mappings for extensionless uris.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I am debuggin in visual studio but testing on different browsers

Comment: @WiktorZychla could you explain this in some more details or provide an example?

Comment: http://www.philipholly.com/post/30520737115/visual-studio-2012-asp-net-mvc-4-web-api-web-config

Comment: @WiktorZychla That links recommends adding runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" to the web.config (which made no difference) and to ensure your using win 7 sp1, I'm running win 8

Comment: It is about extensionless uri handler module.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution that is currently working is one from this question:
[ASP.NET MVC: How to automatically disable [RequireHttps] on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628181/asp-net-mvc-how-to-automatically-disable-requirehttps-on-localhost?rq=1)

So I added the same code:

```
    public class RequireSSLAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public virtual void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
        {
            HandleNonHttpsRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void HandleNonHttpsRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host.Contains("localhost")) return;

        if (!String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL");
        }

        string url = "https://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
    }
}
```

And now it will work fine when I am testing on localhost.
Though what happens if this site is hosted? Would SSL work?

Comment: If this is the localhost domain that caused the issue then most probably the actual non-localhost domain name would cause no issues.