# ASP MVC - securely returning data to client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application, my clients have sensitive data in my database. Now, when my client is making request, how can I securely return this data to him? Is `[RequireHttps]` enough to do that? Mvc will automatically return page via ssl to a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is everything you need. If you add [RequireHttps] to a controllers action MVC will make sure that actions data transmissions are secured using ssl.

If you want to require Https by default you could use an IIS URL Rewrite (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3290382/665689)

Also have a look at

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx

to see more about using SSL in development.