# IIS http to https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm a beginner developer in ASP.NET MVC and I am developing a website without HTTPS (it's will be in the future).

In my website I use with web service that return me in the response a URL (HTTPS).

Our company has IIS configure as HTTPS with SSL.

My questions are:

1. In general will my website will work like this?
2. Can I do redirect from HTTP(my website) to HTTPS(the URL that I do
   the redirect),note: my IIS is HTTPS and SSL?

Comment: Yes you can try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site) to clear you problem.

Comment: As you are using mvc you could do this [RequireHttps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15930990/1398425)